# dojo.dnd.moveable - how to make object NOT move outside of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, dojo

When I make a div moveable by applying dojo.dnd.moveable to it, it can be movet outside of the vieport.
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [dojo.dnd.move.boxConstrainedMoveable](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/dnd#specialized-moveables)

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/gFNS7/12/